# Bad app: ../grid/app-bin/null. App paths need to be absolute, or relative to the appium server install dir, or a URL to compressed file

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, appium, appium-ios

The problem

com.***.pimobile.automation.driver.appium.ios.IOSAppiumDriver - Error occurred while initializing IOS driver. Error: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: Bad app: ../grid/app-bin/null. App paths need to be absolute, or relative to the appium server install dir, or a URL to compressed file, or a special app name. (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)

Environment

```
Appium version (or git revision) that exhibits the issue: 1.6.3
Last Appium version that did not exhibit the issue (if applicable): 1.5.3
Desktop OS/version used to run Appium: MAC EI Capitan
Node.js version (unless using Appium.app|exe): 6.9.5
Mobile platform/version under test: IOS
Real device or emulator/simulator: Simulator
Appium CLI or Appium.app|exe: Appium CLI
Selenium Grid
```

Details

```
Tests are failing intermittently with the error mentioned above.


This is happening when we are running tests in parallel using Grid only and not when the tests are run individually. The same tests were running absolutely fine when they were run without using Grid with the new version.


Fyi, our framework is designed so that the simulators are killed after every test is executed. But what is really happening is during one of the test execution, the simulator is not closing and when the next test gets triggered, the old simulator will still be showing up and then the above error is displayed. Also, if we check the app directory, the app is copied in that directory.

Below are the solutions we have already tried but has never worked:
```

1. To kill the simulator by adding the below code in the tearDown() but this did not work either.
   String kill[] = {"killall","iOS Simulator"};
   Runtime.getRuntime().exec(kill);

   Even with this code:
   String kill[] = {"killall","com.apple.CoreSimulator.CoreSimulatorService"}; in the tear down method.

   2. Tried with both Absolute & relative paths. In both the instances the tests have failed with the above error.

Appium logs

```
`[XCUITest] Error: Bad app: ../grid/app-bin/null. App paths need to be absolute, or relative to the appium server install dir, or a URL to compressed file, or a special app name.
at XCUITestDriver.configureApp$ (../../lib/driver.js:397:13)
at tryCatch (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/babel-runtime/regenerator/runtime.js:67:40)
at GeneratorFunctionPrototype.invoke [as _invoke] (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/babel-runtime/regenerator/runtime.js:315:22)
at GeneratorFunctionPrototype.prototype.(anonymous function) [as throw] (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/babel-runtime/regenerator/runtime.js21)
at GeneratorFunctionPrototype.invoke (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/babel-runtime/regenerator/runtime.js:136:37)
Error: Bad app: ../grid/app-bin/null. App paths need to be absolute, or relative to the appium server install dir, or a URL to compressed file, or a special app name.
at XCUITestDriver.configureApp$ (../../lib/driver.js:397:13)
at tryCatch (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/babel-runtime/regenerator/runtime.js:67:40)
at GeneratorFunctionPrototype.invoke [as _invoke] (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/babel-runtime/regenerator/runtime.js:315:22)
`at GeneratorFunctionPrototype.prototype.(anonymous function) [as throw] (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/babel-runtime/regenerator/runtime.js21)
at GeneratorFunctionPrototype.invoke (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/babel-runtime/regenerator/runtime.js:136:37)
[debug] [XCUITest] Running iOS simulator reset flow
[debug] [XCUITest] Shutting down simulator
[debug] [iOSSim] Killing all iOS Simulators
[debug] [XCUITest] Full reset is on. Cleaning simulator
[debug] [iOSSim] Killing any simulator daemons for 27B739F4-CB2F-48CF-91D3-2DBBB77299C9
[iOSSim] Cleaning simulator 27B739F4-CB2F-48CF-91D3-2DBBB77299C9
[debug] [XCUITest] Resetting simulator
[MJSONWP] Encountered internal error running command: Error: Bad app: ../grid/app-bin/null. App paths need to be absolute, or relative to the appium server install dir, or a URL to compressed file, or a special app name.
at XCUITestDriver.configureApp$ (../../lib/driver.js:397:13)
at tryCatch (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/babel-runtime/regenerator/runtime.js:67:40)
at GeneratorFunctionPrototype.invoke [as _invoke] (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/babel-runtime/regenerator/runtime.js:315:22)
at GeneratorFunctionPrototype.prototype.(anonymous function) [as throw] (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/babel-runtime/regenerator/runtime.js21)
at GeneratorFunctionPrototype.invoke (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/babel-runtime/regenerator/runtime.js:136:37)
[HTTP] <-- POST /wd/hub/session 500 1206 ms - 296
[HTTP] --> GET /wd/hub/status {}
[debug] [MJSONWP] Calling AppiumDriver.getStatus() with args: []
[debug] [MJSONWP] Responding to client with driver.getStatus() result: {"build":{"version":"1.6.3","revision":null}}
[HTTP] <-- GET /wd/hub/status 200 8 ms - 83
[HTTP] --> POST /wd/hub/session {"desiredCapabilities":{"app":"../grid/app-bin/null","newCommandTimeout":360000,"platformVersion":"9.3","automationName":"XCUITest","platformName":"iOS","deviceName":"iPhone 6s","fullReset":true,"platform":"MAC"}}
[debug] [MJSONWP] Calling AppiumDriver.createSession() with args: [{"app":"../grid/app-bin/null","newCommandTimeout":360000,"platformVersion":"9.3","automationName":"XCUITest","platformName":"iOS","deviceName":"iPhone 6s","fullReset":true,"platform":"MAC"},null,null,null,null,null,null]
[Appium] Creating new XCUITestDriver session
[Appium] Capabilities:
[Appium] app: '../grid/app-bin/null'
[Appium] newCommandTimeout: 360000
[Appium] platformVersion: '9.3'
[Appium] automationName: 'XCUITest'
[Appium] platformName: 'iOS'
[Appium] deviceName: 'iPhone 6s'
[Appium] fullReset: true
[Appium] platform: 'MAC'
[debug] [XCUITest] XCUITestDriver version: 2.4.2
[BaseDriver] The following capabilities were provided, but are not recognized by appium: platform.
[BaseDriver] Session created with session id: 1b43ac72-037a-4c38-b7bd-d43a9f5bd0ee
[debug] [XCUITest] Xcode version set to '8.2.1'
[debug] [XCUITest] iOS SDK Version set to '10.2'
[iOSSim] Constructing iOS simulator for Xcode version 8.2.1 with udid '27B739F4-CB2F-48CF-91D3-2DBBB77299C9'
[debug] [XCUITest] Full reset requested. Cleaning and stopping simulator
[debug] [iOSSim] Killing any simulator daemons for 27B739F4-CB2F-48CF-91D3-2DBBB77299C9
[iOSSim] Cleaning simulator 27B739F4-CB2F-48CF-91D3-2DBBB77299C9
[debug] [iOSSim] Killing all iOS Simulators
[XCUITest] Determining device to run tests on: udid: '27B739F4-CB2F-48CF-91D3-2DBBB77299C9', real device: false
[BaseDriver] Using local app '../grid/app-bin/null'
[XCUITest] Error: New app path ../grid/app-bin/null did not have extension .app
at Object.configureApp$ (../../../lib/basedriver/helpers.js:53:11)
at tryCatch (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/babel-runtime/regenerator/runtime.js:67:40)
at GeneratorFunctionPrototype.invoke [as _invoke] (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/babel-runtime/regenerator/runtime.js:315:22)
at GeneratorFunctionPrototype.prototype.(anonymous function) [as next] (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/babel-runtime/regenerator/runtime.js21)
at invoke (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/babel-runtime/regenerator/runtime.js:136:37)
at enqueueResult (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/babel-runtime/regenerator/runtime.js:185:17)
at Promise.F (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/core-js/library/modules/$.export.js:30:36)
at AsyncIterator.enqueue (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/babel-runtime/regenerator/runtime.js:184:12)
at AsyncIterator.prototype.(anonymous function) [as next] (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/babel-runtime/regenerator/runtime.js21)
at Object.runtime.async (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/babel-runtime/regenerator/runtime.js:209:12)
at Object.configureApp (../../../lib/basedriver/helpers.js:32:22)
at XCUITestDriver.configureApp$ (../../lib/driver.js:394:42)
at tryCatch (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/babel-runtime/regenerator/runtime.js:67:40)
at GeneratorFunctionPrototype.invoke [as _invoke] (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/babel-runtime/regenerator/runtime.js:315:22)
at GeneratorFunctionPrototype.prototype.(anonymous function) [as next] (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/babel-runtime/regenerator/runtime.js21)
at invoke (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/babel-runtime/regenerator/runtime.js:136:37)
at enqueueResult (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/babel-runtime/regenerator/runtime.js:185:17)
at Promise.F (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/core-js/library/modules/$.export.js:30:36)
at AsyncIterator.enqueue (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/babel-runtime/regenerator/runtime.js:184:12)
at AsyncIterator.prototype.(anonymous function) [as next] (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/babel-runtime/regenerator/runtime.js21)
at Object.runtime.async (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/babel-runtime/regenerator/runtime.js:209:12)
at XCUITestDriver.configureApp (../../lib/driver.js:364:34)
at XCUITestDriver.start$ (../../lib/driver.js:208:18)
at tryCatch (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/babel-runtime/regenerator/runtime.js:67:40)
at GeneratorFunctionPrototype.invoke [as _invoke] (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/babel-runtime/regenerator/runtime.js:315:22)
at GeneratorFunctionPrototype.prototype.(anonymous function) [as next] (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/babel-runtime/regenerator/runtime.js21)
at GeneratorFunctionPrototype.invoke (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/babel-runtime/regenerator/runtime.js:136:37)
Error: New app path ../grid/app-bin/null did not have extension .app
at Object.configureApp$ (../../../lib/basedriver/helpers.js:53:11)
at tryCatch (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/babel-runtime/regenerator/runtime.js:67:40)
at GeneratorFunctionPrototype.invoke [as _invoke] (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/babel-runtime/regenerator/runtime.js:315:22)
at GeneratorFunctionPrototype.prototype.(anonymous function) [as next] (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/babel-runtime/regenerator/runtime.js21)
at invoke (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/babel-runtime/regenerator/runtime.js:136:37)
at enqueueResult (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/babel-runtime/regenerator/runtime.js:185:17)
at Promise.F (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/core-js/library/modules/$.export.js:30:36)
at AsyncIterator.enqueue (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/babel-runtime/regenerator/runtime.js:184:12)
at AsyncIterator.prototype.(anonymous function) [as next] (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/babel-runtime/regenerator/runtime.js21)
at Object.runtime.async (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/babel-runtime/regenerator/runtime.js:209:12)
at Object.configureApp (../../../lib/basedriver/helpers.js:32:22)
at XCUITestDriver.configureApp$ (../../lib/driver.js:394:42)
at tryCatch (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/babel-runtime/regenerator/runtime.js:67:40)
at GeneratorFunctionPrototype.invoke [as _invoke] (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/babel-runtime/regenerator/runtime.js:315:22)
at GeneratorFunctionPrototype.prototype.(anonymous function) [as next] (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/babel-runtime/regenerator/runtime.js21)
at invoke (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/babel-runtime/regenerator/runtime.js:136:37)
at enqueueResult (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/babel-runtime/regenerator/runtime.js:185:17)
at Promise.F (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/core-js/library/modules/$.export.js:30:36)
at AsyncIterator.enqueue (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/babel-runtime/regenerator/runtime.js:184:12)
at AsyncIterator.prototype.(anonymous function) [as next] (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/babel-runtime/regenerator/runtime.js21)
at Object.runtime.async (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/babel-runtime/regenerator/runtime.js:209:12)
at XCUITestDriver.configureApp (../../lib/driver.js:364:34)
at XCUITestDriver.start$ (../../lib/driver.js:208:18)
at tryCatch (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/babel-runtime/regenerator/runtime.js:67:40)
at GeneratorFunctionPrototype.invoke [as _invoke] (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/babel-runtime/regenerator/runtime.js:315:22)
at GeneratorFunctionPrototype.prototype.(anonymous function) [as next] 
(/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/babel-runtime/regenerator/runtime.js 21)at GeneratorFunctionPrototype.invoke (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/babel-runtime/regenerator/runtime.js:136:37)  ``[XCUITest]Error: Bad app: ../grid/app-bin/null.' App paths need to be absolute, or relative to the appium server install dir, or a URL to compressed file, or a special app name.`
```

[Appium Logs from all the nodes](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B8_69cxt8VqdMWNINHlDVDdTUUU/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: What about this error: 
"[XCUITest] Error: New app path ../grid/app-bin/null did not have extension .app" ?

Comment: @JESii, Is the app copied to the app-bin? Have you checked that?

Comment: @Viswathma I don't use the app at all; had too many problems, I drive my tests from the command-line. As I understand it, Appium.app is currently at at 1.5.3 and is not fully compatible with the 1.6 series or XCUITest

Comment: @JESii, when I mentioned app, I was trying to relate to the Mobile app under test.

Comment: Ah... got it :=) Would need a gist of the full log, plus the commands you are running (appium, ios_webkit_debug_proxy). You can create a gist for review.

Comment: @JESii, [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B8_69cxt8VqdMWNINHlDVDdTUUU/view?usp=sharing). Please take a look and help me with some solution. Thanks!

Comment: @JESii,Did you get sometime to take a look into this?

Comment: OK; what is the command-line for the appium server that you're running?

Comment: And what is in your xcodeconfig (.xcconfig) file? Also, you should consider posting an issue on Appium.  [Here's one](https://github.com/appium/appium/issues/7953) that I recently posted; they've been very responsive with iszues that are well documented.

Comment: @JESii, Here is the command line: appium --nodeconfig ~/grid/nodeconfig.json -a 10.33.86.31 -p 4723 -g ~/grid/log/IPhone6-Simulator_v9_1_appium.log --local-timezone --log-level debug > /dev/null --session-override --default-capabilities '{"showXcodeLog": "true", "automationName": "XCUITest"}'

Comment: Sorry; this is out of my pay grade. I see many sessions in the last (#37) log file, and tons of messages: `2017-03-01 04:38:13:522 - info: [Xcode] 04:38:12.057 xcodebuild[50700:1190467] (LOG ARBITER) Discarding message, buffer is full.`. I strongly urge you to (1) review the sample Appium issue I gave you earlier; (2) post a detailed issue for them to review; (3) truncate log files (by stopping appium) so that only the failing session is included - easier to triage. I've found that well-documented issues get good attention; they're the pros. HTH